# Delete JPGs in dynamic folder

Tags: applescript, automator

I need an automator action that can delete jpgs out of a dynamic folder path.

Essentially what I'd like to do is attach an action to a "template" folder and then copy/paste that folder for each photoshoot. Then, any jpgs that get loaded into the new folder would be deleted.

Is this possible?  Don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

### Creating a Folder Action using Automator:

The following steps describe how to achieve this

1. Launch Automator.
2. Type <kbd>⌘N</kbd>, or choose `File` > `New` from the Menu bar.
3. Select `Folder Action` and click <kbd>Choose</kbd>
4. At the top of the canvas, next to where it says *"Folder Action receives files and folders added to"*

   - Select `Other` from the dropdown menu.
   - Locate the *Template* folder (i.e. the folder that you want to attach the action to).
   - Click <kbd>Choose</kbd>
5. Select `Library` at the top of the panel/column on the left:

   - In the search field type: <kbd>Get Folder Contents</kbd> and drag the `Get Folder Contents` action into the canvas area.
   - Enable the *"Repeat for each sub folder found"* checkbox at the top of the `Get Folder Contents` action (i.e. in the one you just added to the canvas area)
6. Select `Library` at the top of the panel/column on the left again:

   - In the search field type: <kbd>Filter Finder Items</kbd> and drag the `Filter Finder Items` action into the canvas area. Place it below the previously added `Get Folder Contents` action.
   - In the `Filter Finder Items` action that you just added to the canvas area configure it as shown in the image below:

     [image]

     *Note: The file extension is set to `jpg`*
7. Select `Library` at the top of the panel/column on the left again:

   - In the search field type: <kbd>Move Finder Item To Trash</kbd> and drag the `Move Finder Item To Trash` action into the canvas area. Place it below the previously added `Filter Finder Items` action.
8. Type <kbd>⌘S</kbd>, or choose `File` > `Save` from the Menu bar. Let's name the file `delete-jpegs`.

   The file will be saved in:

   ```
   ~/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions/
   ```

---

### Using the Folder Action:

After you've saved the Automator file called `delete-jpegs` (as per step 8 above) you can start adding your image files, *(or any files/folders)*, to the *Template* folder that you chose at step 4. Any files with a `.jpg` file extension will now be moved to the *Trash* *(There may be a slight delay until the Folder Action is triggered)*.

**Reusing the folder action on another target folder:**

> ...attach an action to a "template" folder and then copy/paste that folder for each photoshoot.

The configured folder action will be removed when you duplicate the folder by macOS. So you cannot *"copy/paste that folder for each photoshoot"*.

However, you can add/enable the `delete-jpegs` folder action on another/new folder. To do this:

1. In the *Finder*, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on another/new folder to show the contextual menu and select `Services` > `Folder Actions Setup`
2. When you're prompted to *"Choose a Script to Attach"*:

   - Select `delete-jpegs.worflow` from the list.
   - Click <kbd>Attach</kbd>
3. You should see in the *"Folder Actions Setup"* window two columns.

   - The column on the left lists the folder(s) with action attached,
   - and the column on the right lists the action(s) that are associated with each folder.
   - Each item can be enabled/disabled by toggling the checkboxes.

#### Emptying the Trash:

You'll have noticed that so far the `.jpg` images are only moved to the *Trash* and not deleted per se. To actually empty the *Trash* you'll need to add a another action/step to the canvas area using Automator as follows:

1. After Step 7, (above), select `Library` at the top of the panel/column on the left again:

   - In the search field type: <kbd>Run AppleScript</kbd> and drag the `Run AppleScript` action into the canvas area, placing it below the `Move Finder Item To Trash` action.
   - Completely replace the default script in the `Run AppleScript` action with the following AppleScript code:

     ```
     tell application "Finder"
         empty trash
     end tell
     ```
2. To save the edit, type <kbd>⌘S</kbd>, or choose `File` > `Save`

**Caution:** *This last action/step will empty the Trash - including any files/folders which may already exist that have not been added by the custom `delete-jpegs` folder action.*

---

#### For Reference:

Below provides a general overview of the expected order of actions in the canvas area:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                         │
│    Folder Action receives files         │
│    and folders added to FOLDER_NAME     │
│                                         │
├─────────────────────────────────────────┤
│                                         │
│  ┌───────────────────────────────────┐  │
│  │ Get Folder Contents               │  │
│  ├ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┤  │
│  │ ✔ Repeat for each subfolder found │  │
│  └─────────────────┬─────────────────┘  │
│                    │                    │
│  ┌─────────────────┴─────────────────┐  │
│  │ Filter Finder Items               │  │
│  ├ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┤  │
│  │ Find files where:                 │  │
│  │ All of the following are true     │  │
│  │    File extension is jpg          │  │
│  └─────────────────┬─────────────────┘  │
│                    │                    │
│  ┌─────────────────┴─────────────────┐  │
│  │ Move Finder Items to Trash        │  │
│  └─────────────────┬─────────────────┘  │
│                    │                    │
│  ┌─────────────────┴─────────────────┐  │
│  │ Run AppleScript                   │  │
│  ├ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┤  │
│  │  tell application "Finder"        │  │
│  │    empty trash                    │  │
│  │  end tell                         │  │
│  └───────────────────────────────────┘  │
│                                         │
└─────────────────────────────────────────┘
```